# Usage of "tour de force"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

In English one can use *a tour de force* speaking about a display of a skill, or ingenuity. For instance,

> In 1943 in a tour de force of mathematical physics, Lars Onsager solved the 2D Ising Model.

(source: http://thevirtuosi.blogspot.com/2010/04/onsagers-tour-de-force.html)

> Euler's tour de force on Fermat's last theorem.

Can we use this expression (a French one by the way) in similar contexts in French? Some students of mine didn't know it and those that they did know it believe that it cannot be used in this context. Certains colleagues share the same opinion.

Comment: *DeepL* le traduit sans problème par : « Le tour de force d'Euler sur le dernier théorème de Fermat. », ce qui est tout à fait audible, et représente bien la difficulté surmontée. Vous pouvez (voire devez) laisser le *tour de force* revenir dans sa langue natale recouvrer sa puissance évocatrice … et ceux qui l’ignorent le découvriront :-)

Comment: So there are a few cases of it being used in French. Interesting.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16860)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an expression that retains in French the same unchanging effectiveness it has in English and therefore it can still be use to good effect *and* for  the same contexts that English speaking people use it in. We have been assuming here that the sense is the figurative sense of this expression; it has a literal sense in French and it has been retained in English.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tour)³) Tour de force. Action qui demande beaucoup de force.
> • En portant ce fardeau jusque-là, vous avez fait un tour de force (Ac.). Sur la corde tendue un jeune voltigeur Apprenoit à danser; et déja son adresse, Ses tours de force, de souplesse, Faisoient venir maint spectateur (FLORIAN, Fables, 1792, p. 94).
> Au fig. Exploit, coup de maître.
> • Réussir sa vieillesse, quel tour de force! (MAURIAC, Journal 2, 1937, p. 181).

Here is the defnition in the Shorter OED.

> Pl. **tours de force** (pronounced same) Early 19 century. [Fr.] A feat of strength or skill; an impressive achievement or performance.

Je pense qu'il n'y a aucune raison de ne pas utiliser l'expression dans le cas de prouesses scientifiques, as can be seen in some collected occurrences, it is used in the world of poetry, music, medecine, physics, etc.

ex. La preuve du dernier  théorème de Fermat par Wiles est un tour de force monumental qui a requis sept années du travail de l'auteur et dont le développement s'étale sur la longueur d'un livre entier. (user **LPH**)

---

#### *A few cases of use in French*

*Poetry*

Nouveau Recueil N75 Sur Le Motif (le)
https://books.google.fr
Ainsi, pour les écrivains chinois, l'écriture poïétique consiste surtout en un tour de force du langage (uvenqi) qui ne se trouve qu'à l'intérieur du texte écrit (zili hangjian) et qui, même s'il peut être apprécié de façon très subtile, ne peut pas être ...

*Musique*

(*sarcastic use*)
Vie de Rossini, par m. de Stendhal; ornée des portraits de ...
https://books.google.fr
1824 -
Il faut un tour de force pour être incorrect en écrivant une phrase de mélodie ; rien n'est au contraire plus facile que de faire des fautes en notant dix mesures d'harmonie. . " - La science est nécessaire pour écrire de l'harmonie. Voilà la …

Journal de Paris - Page 447
https://books.google.fr
1809 - ‎
C'est surtout dans l'exécution d'une sonate de piano en si (de Boccherini ), que M. Casimir a étonne son auditoire par les singuliers effets de cette innovation, ou, pour mieux dire, de ce tour de force. | · M." Doyen, élève de M. Lambert, ...

*Politics*

Le huitième jour de la création: un mode d'emploi pour la ... - Page 77
https://books.google.fr
Jacques Neirynck - 2005 -
Encore faut-il que cette superstructure politique accomplisse ce tour de force. ... soviétique qui a engendré une stagnation économique spectaculaire à cause d'un appareil d'Etat trop pesant: dès les années 1920 il a réussi ce tour de force ...

*Agriculture*

https://books.google.fr
François Rozier - 1787 -
Les deux têtes languiront pendant quelques années ; mais insensiblement l'équilibre se rétablira par la distribution égale de la séve. Cette soustraction de l'un ou de l'autre pied d'arbre, peut avec raison être appelée un tour de force dans ce ...

*Medecine*

Dictionaire [sic] abrégé des sciences médicales - Page 531
https://books.google.fr
Nicolas Philibert Adelon - 1821 -
L'habileté consiste à exécuter ce tour de force de telle sorte que, quand l'instrument est arrivé sur la ligne médiane , il soit dans une direction perpendiculaire à l'axe du corps, et que son extrémité ait pénétré dans la vessie. Il est facile de voir ...

Atlas des pathologies oro-maxillo-faciales de l'enfant, du ... - Page vii
https://books.google.fr
G. Couly - 2013 -
Je considère cet atlas comme une œuvre remarquable, un tour de force qui témoigne des immenses expérience et savoir de son auteur. Celui-ci a voulu en faire profiter les médecins et chirurgiens plus jeunes qui, comme lui, consacreront ...

*Mathematics*

Intersections de deux quadriques et pinceaux de courbes de ...
https://books.google.fr
Olivier Wittenberg - 2007 -
En 1993, Swinnerton-Dyer réussit le tour de force de combiner l'argument que l'on vient d'évoquer avec un processus de 2-descente sur une courbe elliptique variable afin d'établir le principe de Hasse pour certaines surfaces de del Pezzo ...

*Physics*

modelisation moleculaire
https://books.google.fr
... picosecondes (103 pas de temps) représente déjà un tour de force. L'ingénieur envisage couramment la maîtrise d'effets perceptibles à notre échelle « macroscopique » (le mm et la seconde) : si la physique statistique nous assure que les ...

*Architecture*

Architecture - Volume 2 - Page 603
https://books.google.fr
Antoine Chrysostome Quatremère de Quincy - 1788 - ‎Lire - ‎Autres éditions
Mais on regarde comme un chef-d'œuvre de hardiesse en fon genre, & un tour de force du constructeur, le, deux tourelles à jour qui sont placées chacune à une des extrémités du jubé : elles renferment les deux escaliers qui mènent à la …

*Computer science*

La communication par la bande: Introduction aux sciences de ...
https://books.google.fr
Daniel BOUGNOUX - 2013 -
Cette œuvre datée de 1735 est une icône, mais qui représente une empreinte, indicielle ; pour la graver, l'artiste a réussi le tour de force typiquement digital* de n'utiliser qu'une seule ligne spiralée qui s'enfle et se rétrécit au gré du modelé.

*Archeology*

Mémoires de la Société archéologique du midi de la France
https://books.google.fr
Société archéologique du midi de la France - 1834 -
... agonistique, à cause des jeux publics, àyöve; , (1) Si l'on voulait absolument, en imitant le Père Hardouin , expliquer ce qui n'est plus explicable , on pourrait , par un tour de force , compléter ainsi la troisième ligne de notre inscription.

*Philosophy*

Unité de l'être et dialectique: l'idée de philosophie ...
https://books.google.fr
Tristan Dagron - 1999 -
I LAPRODUCTIONARTISTIQUE ETL'IDÉE DE SPÉCULATION Le tour de force de Giovanni Pico, ce n'est pas seulement d'avoir repris à Denys ses métaphores mystiques, ni d'avoir subordonné la pensée discursive à une expérience de …

Heidegger 1919-1929: de l'herméneutique de la facticité à la ... - Page 7
https://books.google.fr
Jean-François Marquet, ‎Jean-François Courtine - 1996 -
... il fallait que l'être soit donné, afin d'y pouvoir interroger son sens. Le tour de force de Husserl a justement consisté dans cette mise en présence de l'être, phénoménalement présent dans la catégorie. Par ce tour de force, j'avais enfin le sol .

---

Addition relative au commentaire suivant de user **Dimitris**.

Certains collègues me disent qu'il faut éviter des expressions compliquées durant les cours. Une prof de français m'a dit que ce type d'expression est considéré archaïque et très éloigné du vocabulaire standard des étudiants.

*Réponse*

À mon avis, ces objections ne sont pas valides (vérifiez l'ngram « [tour de force](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tour+de+force&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctour%20de%20force%3B%2Cc0) ») ; l'usage est très courant, loin d'être archaïque ; vérifiez les dates de parution des ouvrages et les domaines d'utilisation. Ce n'est pas compliqué non plus : on veut dire en l'utilisant que de puissant moyens ont été mis en œuvre et que le résultat est à la mesure de ces moyens. Il faut reconnaitre que ce n'est pas du vocabulaire scientifique, mais littéraire. On n'est pas  tenu en parlant de science de s'en tenir au seul vocabulaire scientifique, *tout au contraire*. Même dans le cours d'une démonstration orale formelle on est autorisé à formuler ici et là des appréciations sur les  processus considérés à condition qu'il s'agisse de quelque chose de remarquable. Comment le faire autrement qu'en termes littéraires ? Évidemment, si par exemple vous pensez qu'intituler un chapitre d'étude sur le traitement de la théorie des lois fondamentales de la  dynamique « Le tour de force des lois fondamentales de la dynamique » vous restez dans les normes, vous vous trompez : vous donnez à votre exposé des connotations que traditionnellement l'on n'admet pas dans ce domaine et ne pas permettre ces connotations devrait demeurer la norme selon mon opinion ; c'est très bien ainsi. C'est peut-être donc en ce sens que vous recevez les conseils dont vous parlez, mais les explications ne correspondent pas ; vous remarquerez que l'expression apparaitra en anglais comme en français dans des préfaces, des textes introductifs, où on situe un contexte scientifique, historique ou autre, parce qu'il permet de mettre en perspective la discussion purement scientifique à venir, et l'expression n'est pas utilisée dans cette dernière. Néanmoins, n'oublions pas cependant que de nos jours on trouve des ouvrages de  mathématiques qui présentent leur sujet de façon non conforme, récréative, mais la perte en formalisme ne fait de ces ouvrages que des créations marginales, des curiosités.
Il est alors possible que la motivation pour le rejet de cette expression dans son sens figuré soit simplement fondé sur ses racines (le sens littéral) et donc sur la base de son existence indépendamment de sa spécialisation à quelque contexte que ce soit ; dans ce cas on passe à un domaine de considérations de la langue plutôt philosophique et il y a peu de notions auxquelles se référer. La discussion dans ce domaine va probablement trop loin compte tenu de ce qui est permis dans le cadre du FSE.

Comment: Une réponse...tour de force ! Je vous remercie. Toutefois, je me demande pourquoi plusieurs étudiant.e.s ne connaissent pas cette expression et même certain.e.s collègues me suggèrent de ne pas l'utiliser dans le contexte mathématique/physique.

Comment: @Dimitris Que les étudiants ne connaissent pas l'expression peut se comprendre en cela que se sont des scientifiques et que en Franc elle pourrait ne pas être autant utilisée en mathématiques et en physique;  cependant, on la trouve dans toutes sortes de contextes scientifiques et donc pourquoi pas dans les sciences physiques. Il faudrait toujours demander à ces personnes qui vous déconseillent quelque chose de vous donner des explications; je ne comprend pas qu'ils s'en tiennent à un simple « Il ne faut pas le dire. ». Moi-même, je ne vois pas ce qui empêcherait d'utiliser cette expression.

Comment: Merci. Certains collègues me disent qu'il faut éviter des expressions compliquées durant les cours. Une prof du français m'a dit que ce type d'expressions sont considérées archaïques et très éloignées du vocabulaire standard des étudiants.

Comment: @Dimitris — Il y a plus d’un demi-siècle, la mission des professeurs étaient d’enrichir le vocabulaire, source d’inventivité, de solutions nouvelles  et de sérendipité …

Comment: @Dimitris Comme la réplique à ce dernier commentaire est trop longue, je la place dans la réponse.

Comment: Merci encore ! Je lis votre nouvelle réponse avec plaisir:-)!

Answer (score 2):

"En 1943 dans un tour de force de physique mathématique, Lars Onsager a résolu..." is correct.